# How to handle entrypoints nested in folders with amazon sagemaker pytorch estimator?

Tags: python, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I am attempting to run a training job on amazon sagemaker using the python-sagemaker-sdk, estimator class.

I have the following

```
estimator = PyTorch(entry_point='training_scripts/train_MSCOCO.py',
                            source_dir='./',
                            role=#dummy_role,
                            train_instance_type='ml.p3.2xlarge',
                            train_instance_count=1,
                            framework_version='1.0.0',
                            output_path=#dummy_output_path,
                            hyperparameters={'lr': 0.001,
                                             'batch_size': 32,
                                             'num_workers': 4,
                                             'description': description})
```

role and output_path hidden for privacy.

I get the following error, "No module named training_scripts\train_MSCOCO".

When I run python -m training_scripts.train_MSCOCO the script runs fine. However when I pass `entry_point='training_script.train_MSCOCO.py` it will not run as, "No file named "training_scripts.train_MSCOCO.py" was found in directory "./"".

I am confused as to how to run a nested training script from the top level of my repository within AWS sagemaker, as they seem to have conflicting path needs, one in python module dot notation, the other in standard filepath slash notation.

Answer (score 2):

Either one of these will work:

```
estimator = PyTorch(entry_point='training_scripts/train_MSCOCO.py',
                    role=#dummy_role,
                    ...

estimator = PyTorch(entry_point='train_MSCOCO.py',
                    source_dir='training_scripts',
                    role=#dummy_role,
                    ...
```

Comment: Hello, to clarify, there is other source code in the source_dir './'. Neither of these solutions properly import the source dir.

Comment: There is currently an issue with the sagemaker sdk that prevents entry_point values that include a path from being handled correctly within the training container, when you also provide a source_dir value. Julien's solution will work, but you may need to reorg your source code.

Comment: Any updates on that? I still can't pass my folder properly, tried `./`, `.` and even `os.getcwd()`